# TextBox wont update on Main Window WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a program that intercepts an SMS from a SMS Modem and then it is meant to update a `TextBox` on the main window from another class the code I have is:

MainWindow:

```
Class MainWindow
Public WithEvents SMScon As SMSComms
Private Delegate Sub GetDisplay(ByVal SMS As SMSMessage)

Public Sub GetFromSMSComms(SMS As SMSMessage) Handles SMScon.SMSListChanged
    If tb_recievedmessages.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() Then
        DisplaySMS(SMS)
    Else
        tb_recievedmessages.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, New GetDisplay(AddressOf DisplaySMS), SMS)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DisplaySMS(ByVal SMS As SMSMessage)
    Debug.WriteLine("Writing To TextBox")
    tb_recievedmessages.Text() = SMS.MessageText
End Sub
End Class
```

the SMS in captured in a different class:

SMSComms.vb:

```
Public Class SMSComms

   Public Event SMSListChanged(ByVal SMS As SMSMessage)

Private Delegate Sub GetDisplaySMSCallback(ByVal SMS As List(Of String))

Public Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

    Dim rxString As String
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim newMsg As New SMSMessage

    RemoveHandler SMSPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

    Thread.Sleep(100)
    rxString = SMSPort.ReadExisting()
    rxString = TrimCRLF(rxString)

    index = NewSMSIndex(rxString)
    If index > -1 Then

        newMsg = ReadSMS(index)
        If newMsg.Index > -1 Then


            AddHandler SMSListChanged, AddressOf Main.GetFromSMSComms

            RaiseEvent SMSListChanged(newMsg)


        End If

    End If
    RemoveHandler SMSListChanged, AddressOf Main.GetFromSMSComms
    AddHandler SMSPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

End Sub
End Class
```

Now the SMS object gets passed to the main window from the SMSComms class and i use the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(), to call the main thread but when it gets to the sub that writes to the textbox, the textbox does not update on the main UI.

can anyone tell me why?? or how to make it update??

Comment: have you set some breakpoints and stepped through?  is your message correct?  is the message somehow empty, so the textbox is correct?  Isn't textbox.text a property?  `tb_recievedmessages.Text() = blah` seems wrong to me.

Comment: You've got too much code my friend. Please read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page to find out how to reduce it, then please edit your question to do just that.

Comment: BTW, please learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: the message that is getting to tb_recievedmessages.Text() is correct SMS.Messagetext is a string, so i cant work out why it wont write to the textbox

Comment: @JohnGardner  Visual Basic allows parens on property setters

Comment: @ajg724  what version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: @WaltRitscher ah, the fun of vb syntax! :D

Comment: the Answer in the end was that i wasnt passing the mainwindow into the SMSComms class, so there wasnt actually anything to update